# Object.estimated (Kinda of Date object) not being processed to Date() type

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, typescript

I'm receiving this Object.estimated from query to a MongoDB:

```
Object {estimated: Mon Aug 03 2015 02:00:00 GMT-0500 (COT)}
```

Then I try to make a Date with it:

```
new Date(referenceToEstimated)
```

But I get error: `Invalid Date`

I'm using angular2 with typescript by the way, I also tried using datePipe from angular2 and it still gives me error.

I need to make estimated object a Date type object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` constructor doesn't know what to do with your arbitrary object.

You can try `new Date(referencedToEstimated.estimated)` instead.